redeclaration error for function to truncate a string in php
At the moment, I'm programming on a blog website where several blog posts will be listed!
For the first post it's already working with the attached code snippet but unfortunately not for all the following ones!
I've got following error: "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare truncateString()" for the code below:
function truncateString($string, $length, $ellipsis = '...') {

    if (strlen($string) <= $length) {
        return $string;
    }

    $truncatedString = substr($string, 0, $length);
    $lastSpace = strrpos($truncatedString, ' ');

    if ($lastSpace !== false) {
        $truncatedString = substr($truncatedString, 0, $lastSpace);
    }

    return $truncatedString . $ellipsis;
}

$string = $post['body'];
$truncatedText = truncateString($string, 200);

echo $truncatedText;

Do you you have any recommendations, ideas how to solve it?
I would love to get it working for all the posts and featured posts on the website!
enter image description here

It means you have a function with the same name somewhere else (in the same source code file or onother). Another possible cause is that you are including twice the same file containing that function, this problem can be solved using require_once insetead of require or include_once instead of include

Note also that in PHP the names of the functions are case insensitive so truncateString is the same as truncatestring or TruncateString

With this generally formulated function, I'm applying it to every further blog post that should be listed on the website, but, unfortunately, in this respect I'm using no require or include at all ! Any suggestions?

I've added a picture of the website screenshot with the supposed blog posts (it should show 6 in total but one could only see the first two, with only the first one working as planned) above in order to imagine how it looks like - maybe that helps!

If you have common functions, you should extract them to a single file (makes it easier to change once and all uses get the updated functionality) and then require_once() this new file.

The error message tells, that you have included the same file (containing the function) twice. Use includeonce and requireonce instead of include and require.

I thought it was clear: the first thing to do is see if there are multiple functions with the same name. A simple way is to try renaming the offending function and see if that works. If this doesn't work, and you don't explicitly include the same code, it may mean that the system is doing it. However, you are not saying which system you are using (a CMS?) and in what context you are inserting your code (a shortcode?) so it is a bit difficult to give a more precise answer

Thanks, Nigel - that worked out well! I just put the function in one seperate php-file and have included (include _once) the funcion in my blog.php as follows:
include_once 'blog/truncate.php';
$string = $post['body'];
$truncatedText = truncateString($string, 200);
That was my missing link, thanks a lot for the learning !

That was my missing link, thanks a lot for the learning !I've just implemented a whole login system for different admins and users (with according dashboard) I granted different rights to post or even add users/categories in case of the admin! All data were then saved in a php database where all the blog info is coming back and read out from!
Thanks, also to TUPKAP and the others joining into the discussion! It's always a bit difficult to explain what's the larger context and application one is using it for!

As said in other replies, this means you have a function declared with the same name.
By the way, you could simplify your function like that :
function truncateString($string, $length, $ellipsis = '...') {
    return strlen($string) > $length 
        ? rtrim(substr($string, 0, strrpos(substr($string, 0, $length + 1), ' '))) . $ellipsis 
        : $string;
}

$string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$truncatedText = truncateString($string, 20);

echo $truncatedText;


Thanks, Mat ! But, this version unfortunately doesn't take into account that the site where the text is truncated should not cut the last word and should show the full last word concerning the length!

You are right, my very bad...
I edited the function so it fullfills your needs :)

The problem was not the function, but the inclusion of it.

If you're unsure about how the file was included, you can surround the declaration with a "guard code"
if (!function_exists('truncateString')) {
    function truncateString($string, $length, $ellipsis = '...') {
        // the code
    }
}

That way you should not have a problem with multiple include instead of include_once.

This seems a like a very dirt way of 'solving' the problem. You are actually just ignoring it.
